# VideoJS player custom mute/unmute toggle

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, addeventlistener, video.js

I need to add a custom mute/unmute button to a [VideoJs](https://videojs.com/) player (when I click on the button if it's muted it should unmute and if it's unmuted then it should mute).

I tried to do this in the following way with JavaScript but it doesn't work. Could you help me fix this?

```js
const muteButton = document.querySelector(".mute-btn11");

muteButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var video = videojs("myVideo");
  const booleanValue = video.muted.valueOf();
  console.log(booleanValue);

  if (booleanValue == true) {
    video.muted(false);
  } else {
    video.muted(true);
  }
});
```

```html
<video controls autoplay playsinline id="myVideo" class="video-js vjs-16-9 vjs-big-play-centered"></video>
<button class="mute-btn11"> Mute </button>
```

Comment: Does spelling "playsinline" with a capital "I" solve it? As mentioned here: https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/4222

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Muted is a function of VideJS Player object.

You can get the Player object of your video using this method.

```
var vp = videojs('myVideo').player();
```

Then, you can invoke muted() function to get the boolean value.

```
var muted = vp.muted();
```

To set use muted method with true or false parameter

```
var muted = vp.muted( true ); 

var muted = vp.muted( false );
```

Comment: hmmmm nice , however i not understand why `setMuted` function not worked when i call it.  https://docs.videojs.com/html5#setMuted

Comment: Please, provide your code so I can try to help you